# Eval() replacement in either UnityScript or C# with Unity

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine, unityscript

As far as I can see my question hasn't been answered before. I am using Unity to create an app for Windows Phone 8 , and I want to get the user's input and execute it as code. Now usually with JavaScript one could just use eval("code here") but Unity doesn't like that, and says that eval() is not allowed with my target (WP8).

So my question is - how could I execute a string as code in EITHER C# or UnityScript without using eval(), and without relying on window or attaching a script to the document - basically so it works with Unity.

For example, if I could use eval I would do : eval("createCuboid(0, 1, 2)");

Thanks for the help.

Edit:
So I am making an app that allows the user to input one line of code in GUI.TextField. When the user click a button, it will then get their code and run it. In my example createCuboid(0, 1, 2) I have my own function that creates a cuboid to the user's specification (as seen in parameters).

The reason I want this is because I want the user to be able to freely manipulate the 3D environment without having to do something a bit more constricted - for instance, having to tap a button with createCuboid on it, then enter parameters in multiple fields. I have multiple functions the user can call to manipulate the environment.

Does that help?

Comment: Could you post a bit more about what problem you're trying to solve? Because you shouldn't have to do this and it sounds like you're going about something in completely the wrong way.

Comment: As far as I know, C# doesn't offer something like that. You could write your own interpreter that parses the parameter and use reflection to set everything up, but that will be a lot of work (and potentially very dangerous).

Comment: Anything for JavaScript? I've kind of reached the conclusion that doing so in C# is impossible.

Comment: Note that it is indeed possible to [compile and execute c# code at runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6(v=vs.110).aspx) in .net framework, but usually these types of features are not available for mobile operating systems like Win Phone 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you need to let the user write the code?
That is very dangerous. If you want to allow to user to create objects (like cube) in run-time, let the user choose what they want to create, use fields to get function params (check if correct here too.) and create the object.

Maybe something like:

```
List<Cubes> cubes = new List<Cubes>();
int create = /* read */;
switch (create)
{
    case 0: {
        int x = /* ask for x */
        int y = /* ask for y */

        cubes.Add(createCuboid(x, y, 0));
        break;
    }

    /* etc */
}
```

If you want to let the user delete the cube, get from the list and delete it.
And.. yes, this code is just to clarify what i want to say.

Comment: Thanks! That is a better idea.